# Why is parameter $q$ of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ being root of unity a problem?

Tags: lie-algebra, integrable-systems

I am recently studying the quantum groups and the exactly solvable models.

I understand the solution of the Yang-Baxter equation is elements in $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$.

I am informed that when $q$ is the root of unity, there is a massive center in this quantum group.

However, I fail to see that.

And I also very much confused that what is the terrible consequence of this massive center?
Or what is the meaning of center of quantum groups in physics?

Comment: Study up pp 7,8 of [this talk](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/paradig.pdf); the figure of p 8 is at the end of the paper. Appreciate the  singularities of the deformed Casimir invariant.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will study this document immediately.